# select record which is not present in other table in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i have used the following query to select rows from tables.

```
Table 1:

id  description status add_date   topicid 
 1   xyz         0      22-3-13     5   
 2   pqr         0      21-3-13     5
 3   abc         0      20-3-13     5
 4   sdd         0      22-3-13     5


Table2:

id     otherid    
1       2  
2       3
```

This query gives me all the record from table1 but i want to select those record which is not in table2.
like table1 'id'  not present in table2 'otherid'.
In my case want to select record from table1 for id 1 and 4.because which is not present in table2 as 'otherid'.

```
$topicid = 5;

$q =$this->db->select(array(
            't1.id as id',
            't1.description',
            't1.topicid',
            't1.add_date'))
            ->from('table1 AS t1')
            ->where('t1.topicid',$topicid)
            ->where('t1.status',0)
            ->order_by('t1.add_date DESC)->get();
```

Comment: select * from table1 .t1 where t1.topicid = $topicid and ti.status = 0 and t1.id not in (select t2.otherid from table2 as t2 ,table1 as t1 where t2.otherid = t1.id) maybe this will help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this query will work

```
$topicid = 5;

$q =$this->db->select(array(
            't1.id as id',
            't1.description',
            't1.topicid',
            't1.add_date'))
            ->from('table1 AS t1')
            ->where('t1.topicid',$topicid)
            ->where('t1.status',0)
            ->where('t1.id NOT IN (select otherid from table2)',NULL,FALSE)
            ->order_by('t1.add_date DESC)->get();
```

Comment: I used this answer, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$select =   array(
                't1.id as id',
                't1.description',
                't1.topicid',
                't1.add_date'
            );
$this->db
        ->select($select)
        ->join('Table2','Table2.otherid = Table1.id','left')
        ->where('Table2.otherid IS','NULL')
        ->where('Table1.topicid',$topicid)
        ->where('Table1.status',0)
        ->get('Table1');
```